# SQL unable to alter view having DECLARE statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to alter the view below:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Win.v_TodayMin365]
AS

    declare @tblOut table(Dates Date)
    declare @cnt INT = -365
    while @cnt < 0
    Begin
            set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
            insert into @tblOut (Dates) values(cast(dateadd(day,@cnt,getdate()) as Date))
    END
    select * from @tblOut
    deallocate @tblOut
    deallocate @cnt
GO
```

The code as such works (if I highlight all between AS and GO and hit Execute, I get the expected output), but I can't run it as ALTER VIEW. Then, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.
>   Expecting '(', SELECT or WITH

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: you need to create a stored procedure.. not a view.. or maybe a table value function

Comment: Foundation thuis post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114826/sql-views-no-variables

Comment: Just a touch more explanation - views are just canned queries.  You can't alter data with a view.  You can only retrieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `Declare` a variable inside a `View`

Actually you don't need to use `While` loop for this. Use a tally table trick to generate dates much efficient than the `while` loop approach

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Win.v_TodayMin365]
AS
  WITH E1(N)
       AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1), --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N)
       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a,E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N)
       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a,E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
       calendar
       AS (SELECT Dateadd(dd, Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY n), Dateadd(yy, -1, Cast(Getdate() + 1 AS DATE))) AS dates
           FROM   E4 l)
  SELECT *
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  dates <= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)
```

This even can be converted to `Table valued function` or a `Stored Procedure`.